# Pulling values out of a list of ints and floats in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list of values:

```
2 0.75
1 0.01
2 1.0
3 0.8
```

I'm going over the list and want to split the pairs into two variables.

For testing, I've just tried printing them out. However, this gives me an error "Prelude.read: no parse":

```
getCountProb :: Handle -> IO ()
getCountProb inh = do
    countProb <- hGetLine inh
    let cp = read countProb :: (Integer, Float)
    let test = fst cp
    print test
```

Comment: `read "(1, 0.75)" :: (Int , Float)` returns `(1,0.75)`. `let [x, y] = words "1 0.75" in (read x :: Int, read y :: Float)` returns `(1,0.75)`.

Comment: @Elmex80s Yes, my thinking was put the values in a tuple and then pull them out using fst and snd. Is there a better way to go about it?

Comment: see updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`countProb` is `"2 0.75"`, which is not parse-able by `read`. You could split it into two parse-able segments by using `words` which splits values on whitespace, though.

```
let [x, y] = words countProb
```

then you can combine to `:: (Integer, Float)` by reading each individually.

```
let cp = (read x, read y) :: (Integer, Float)
```

---

Alternatively, and considerably more complicated, you could use `Text.Printf.printf` to format your text to something `read` **can** parse.

```
let [x, y] = words countProb
    fmtd   = printf "(%s, %s)" x y
    cp     = read fmtd :: (Integer, Float)
```

Comment: The last one doesn't actually work.  `::` isn't a cast.

Comment: (It will work in ghci because ghci cheats with `NoMonomorphismRestriction` -- but that causes the first line to be evaluated twice)

Comment: @luqui oh good call. I'll remove the last alternative (since it's not great to begin with